# How to validate Bootstrap Form Helpers DatePicker as Required or Not Empty?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-form-helper

I have tried using the data-bv-notempty attribute without success. Code sample below:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-registration" action="/submit.php" method="post" >
  <div class='form-group'>
  <div class='field-group'>
    <label for='user_name' class='col-sm-5 control-label' id='label__user_name'>Name<sup>*</sup>:</label>
    <div class='col-sm-7 control-data'><input type='text' name='user_name' required data-bv-notempty  class='form-control' ></div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
  <div class='field-group'>
    <label for='date_entry' class='col-sm-5 control-label' id='label__date_entry'>Date<sup>*</sup>:</label>
    <div class='col-sm-7 control-data'>
    <div class='bfh-datepicker' data-name='date_entry' data-date='' data-bv-notempty data-max='today'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class='text-center'><button type='button' id='btn-submit' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'>Continue</button></div>
  </form>
```

The first field user_name is validated successfully via the attribute data-bv-notempty, but not the date_entry field. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

Discovered something strange. I added the `data-bv-field='date_entry'` attribute to the `bfh-datepicker` div. Now if a date is selected first and validation performed, it passes the validation. On the other hand if validation is performed first, fails validation, and a date is entered after the failed validation, the red cross will remain and validation still does not go through. Bizarre.

Comment: I haven't used that myself, but I would expect you probably need to add the `required` attribute to your `div.bfh-datepicker`.

Comment: required data-bv-notempty why are you not making it required as well?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `required` attribute was tried before, no effect. Please note that the attributes are added to the `<div>` and not the `<input>` element, as input was dynamically generated by the bootstrap-form-helpers code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's any way to specify your own custom attributes on the `input`, but you should be able to add the `required` attribute with Javascript after Bootstrap Form Helper constructs the `input`.

```
<div class="bfh-datepicker" id="the-required-datepicker"></div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#the-required-datepicker input').attr('required','required');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how to set country from javascript